# libeigen3-dev on hydro?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to build a package that uses libeigen3, but there is no stacks. "roscd eigen" shows that it isn't there. Searching reveals that stacks for hydro isn't there while at the same time it seems it can be installed manually. So how should I proceed ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168301/libeigen3-dev-on-hydro-?/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Eigen is a system dependency, not a ROS package. Have you tried installing using apt?

```
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev
```

You should also be able to install the dependencies for packages using rosdep, assuming your packages are in the src folder (just change the src argument if your packages are elsewhere).

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-22**:
Yes, I did. And it got me confused somehow. Indeed I installed it that way, but while on Electric it works, on Hydro eigen can't be resolved. The paths are fine. I got to this because of cv_bridge: on Electric my code compiles while on Hydro it doesn't. Testing this, I also got this eigen error.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-22**:
I think eigen moved from a ROS package to an external dependency between Electric and Hydro. It'll be easier to troubleshoot if you include the exact build errors you're seeing in your question.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-22**:
The error on eigen is:
/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/Polynomials:4:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
while it clearly is there:
$ls /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-23**:
It sounds like it's expecting /usr/include/eigen3 to be in your include path. Are you sure you're calling find_package for eigen in your CMakeLists correctly?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-23**:
I compared the CMakeLists of the Electric and Hydro versions and they're identical.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-24**:
Can you add your CMakeLists and the include lines from one file that is failing to your question?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-24**:
My include lines mess up after posting; are there coding tags I can/should use ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-25**:
Yes; you can either select your code and use the code button in the editor GUI, or simply indent each line by four spaces.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-25**:
Odd, I have no code button and 4 spaces gives me the same messed up lines. Will post them anyway.
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/Polynomials>

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-25**:
You should edit your question rather than adding additional information as a comment. (formatting in comments isn't supported).

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-25**:
It looks like you're specifying the eigen3 include prefix explicitly, and the unsupported headers expect that directory to be on your include path. Is this a rosbuild package?

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-26**:
The package in which I use eigen3 is rosbuild. I've checked $PATH and $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and compared to the machine with Electric. The paths arent exactly the same, but similar enough. On the testing x86 machine running Hydro, it doesn't build either. Right now I don't know if it's due ROS.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-26**:
OK, found the core of the problem. CMakeLists had yet to be adapted for ROS newer than Electric. Since Eigen is no longer a ROS package I didn't think this was necessary. Still getting errors but at least eigen3 is found.